# How can I drastically reduce line spacing between items in thebibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Is there an option to reduce the line spacing in the bibliography? I'm using thebibliography environment. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Any answer to your question will depend strongly on *how* you changed from singlespacing (the default) to something like doublespacing.

Comment: So, do please provide some information on how your document has moved away from singlespacing.

Comment: You're right, sorry, actually I didn't change anything in my document, I'm just using default singlespacing. I just would like to have smaller line spacing in the whole bibliography. Thanks